# Topology on the dual of a Frechet space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, locally-convex-spaces

If $F$ is a Frechet space, is there any locally convex space topology on the dual
$F'$, such that for each local diffeomorphism $f$ from an open subset $U$ of $F$ to $F$,
the map $U \times F' \longrightarrow F'$ is smooth?

Comment: Your question *is not precise* enough. You should specify how you define "the map $U \times F' \longrightarrow F'$ " and also in what sense you want it to be smooth.

Comment: Smoothness in the sense of Michal and Bastiani (also known Keller). And the map is defined by $(x, \lambda) \mapsto \lambda \circ df $. Actually, the question is how to define a smooth structure on cotangent Frechet bundle?

Answer (score 4):

This map is not smooth for every vector space topology on the dual space, see Remark I.3.9. in Neeb, K.-H. "Towards a Lie theory of locally convex groups" 2006 for an explicit counterexample.

Thus the cotangent bundle does not carry a (natural) smooth structure for Fréchet manifolds and one has to specify what one understands under *smooth* differential forms more directly. The usual way is to require the chart representation of the differential $k$-form $\alpha$ to be smooth as as a map $\alpha: U \times F^k \to \mathbb{R}$ (see Definition I.4.1 in the above paper).

Comment: Thanks, it was suggested a replacement for a cotangent bundle which is a sub-bundle of the cotangent bundle with a natural smooth structure (Neeb, Remark II.3.5, Monastir Summer School: Infinite-Dimensional Lie Groups). A question which arise now is that if we have for example a functional f on manifold the differential df is the element of the cotangent bundle, is there a replacement of the cotangent bundle which df belongs to?

Comment: @ Kaveh Eftekharinasab: If instead of the Michal−Bastiani smoothness you choose to use the Frölicher−Kriegl−Michor "Convenient Calculus", then you can construct the cotangent bundle in the usual manner. However, then there is the drawback that a smooth map with domain a nonmetrizable space need not be continuous.

Comment: You can still form the exterior bundle (and in particular the cotangent bundle) in the set-theoretic sense. So the differential $df$ still belongs to the cotangent bundle, however you don't have a smooth structure on it and thus you cannot say that the map $m \mapsto (df)_m$ is smooth in the usual way.

Comment: Thanks for comments, It seems that there is a replacement for a cotangent bundle with a manifold structure in standard calculus (Michal and Bastiani). If we define
the topology of uniform convergence on all compact sets of a cotangent space. If $\beta$ is a bornology on the model space. Then the $\beta$-cotangent bundle which is the union of the cotangent spaces with the above topology has a structure of a manifold, see Wurzbacher, Fermionic Second Quantization.

Comment: It's a long time since I looked at Prof. Wurzbachers work, so take the following with a grain of salt: I wasn't to convince that his definition of a cotangent bundle does not run in the same kind of complications, i.e. it is not locally trivial in a smooth manner (since the above result of Neeb yields a counter example for every vector space topology on the dual). If I remember it correctly, Wurzbacher just says "this bundle is obviously locally trivial" and don't comment on possible issues. Kaveh, do you think his work is rigorous?

Comment: Tobias, I agree, it would be better if he put more details; it is a bit hard to follow this work. However, this paper is quit interesting and I think this definition of $\beta$-cotangent bundle is suitable for my purpose which is getting a Finsler structure on a cotangent bundle by using pairing. He says that the $\beta$-exterior bundle is locally trivial if all continuous linear maps, map the bornology into itself, but I dont know how often can it occurs in practice.